# How does this command substitution with "cat" work?

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I've found a shell script that has a line like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfile=$1

variable=`cat`
# other commands go here
```

I don't understand, will that variable contain? When I tried the same thing in the command prompt, it just waited for stdin to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script probably relies on being executed with a non-tty stdin, in which case the variable will contain its whole content without need for any user interaction :

```
#!/bin/bash
variable=`cat`
echo $variable
```

```
$ echo foo | script.sh
foo
$ echo foo > some_file
$ script.sh < some_file
foo
```

Comment: It works exactly the same way even if stdin *is* a tty; it just waits for input (which the user can terminate with Control-D, or whatever key their terminal uses to signal end-of-input).

Comment: @chepner right, I didn't explain that because Benjamin W.'s answer already covered it. What I meant to say is that if the script is meant to be executed with a non-tty stdin then the variable will contain the whole content of that stdin without requiring the user to know about Control-D

Answer (score 3):

This will expect keyboard input (or read from standard input if invoked in a pipe), and after closing standard input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>D</kbd>, `variable` will contain what was typed.

The much more common way of achieving this is using the `read` builtin, though:

```
$ read variable
foo
$ declare -p variable
declare -- variable="foo"
```

Answer (score -1):

Cat takes two files and display both of them 
if you do cat file1.txt file2.txt on your terminal any that your files exists and contain data it will output the content of file1.txt then the content of file2.txt if you want more infos look at man pages over the internets for more precisions 
[http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html][1]

Comment: From the manual you linked : `[FILE]...` : `cat` accepts a list of files, whose length doesn't have to be 2 ; `With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.` : that's what the command does in OP's script